# How to fill default gateway with null value via batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

this is batch script to set ip address, subnet mask and default gateway via batch/bat:
`netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0 1.2.3.254 1`

how scripts to set the default gateway with null value?
because with this script error occurs: 0.0.0.0 is not an acceptable value for gateway.
`netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0 0.0.0.0 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the default gateway to `0.0.0.0` because it's simply not valide gateway IP. You could as well try to set it to `300.FF.~%&.ö`. It must be at least `1.0.0.0`. If you want to set no gateway replace `0.0.0.0` by `none`. For more information check https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netsh_int_ip.mspx?mfr=true